# MXNet Quick Installation for R in Ubuntu 12

Tags: r, bash, ubuntu, mxnet

The installation instructions at http://mxnet.io/get_started/ubuntu_setup.html tell to run the .sh file after cd into an appropriate directory but it throws following error:

```
avijit@avijit-Inspiron-3521:~/mxnet/setup-utils$ bash install-mxnet-ubuntu-r.sh
MXNet root folder: /home/avijit/mxnet/
Building MXNet core. This can take few minutes...
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

It seems to have some additional steps prior to it, BUT are ommitted from the installation steps in the link. What's is the issue?

NOTE: I'm following "Quick Installation" at http://mxnet.io/get_started/ubuntu_setup.html#install-mxnet-for-r and NOT building it from source.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try run `cp make/config.mk .` before you run
`cd ~/mxnet/setup-utils
bash install-mxnet-ubuntu-r.sh`?

It is because of missing the `config.mk` in the $MXNET_HOME.